# iOS 9+ - Swift 2.1 -> maximum value

Tags: ios, swift2

I have this code:

```
    var w = 0
    var h = 0
    for i in 1...am
    {
        if w > Int(screenSize.width)
        {
            w = 0
            h += CHeight
        }

        //some other code

        w += CWidth
```

so the value W is a part of the screen width, and it can be not "perfectly" equal to the screen width while adding them together.
the IF doing it's job only when the part value(W) larger then screen width. but how to make it so the IF will work when value W will be just before the end of screen width (doesn't go over it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if w > Int(screenSize.width) - CWidth
{
    w = 0
    h += CHeight
}
```